# Передача массива в функцию целиком

Tags: php

Изначально как-то работало, но мне пришлось переделать скрипт и теперь он в разы сложнее, в придачу и передача массива в функцию проходит неверно и в функции я не получаю данных.

```
$cx1 = -1.2; 
$cx2 = 0; 
$delta = 0.5;

function f_compare($x1, $x2, $type) {
    global $x1, $x2;
    print_r ($x1);
    print_r ($x2);
    return true;
}

//Исследующий поиск
function cycle($cx1, $cx2, $delta, $type) {
    global $cx1, $cx2, $delta; $x = array(); $x2 = array();
    if ($type==1) {$x[0]=$cx1; $x2[0]=$cx2;}
    print_r ($x);
    print_r ($x2);
    echo f_compare($x,$x2,$type);
}
cycle($cx1, $cx2, $delta, 1);
```

Вывод в функции `cycle` сработает, но вывод в функции `f_compare` нет, почему так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите global в функциях, вы затираете ими ваши аргументы, если первая функция срабатывает за счет того, что ваши аргументы определены в глобальной области видимости, то функция f_compare(), там уже не находит $x1 и $x2, так как они находятся в области видимости функции cycle().

```
<?php
$cx1 = -1.2; 
$cx2 = 0; 
$delta = 0.5;

function f_compare($x1, $x2, $type) {
    print_r ($x1);
    print_r ($x2);
    return true;
}

//Исследующий поиск
function cycle($cx1, $cx2, $delta, $type) {
    $x = array();
    $x2 = array();
    if ($type==1) {$x[0]=$cx1; $x2[0]=$cx2;}
    print_r ($x);
    print_r ($x2);
    echo f_compare($x,$x2,$type);
}
cycle($cx1, $cx2, $delta, 1);
```

Comment: Оу, вы правы. Просто изначально было вообще странно, нужно было и передавать массив и указывать его глобально, без одного из них функция почему-то вовсе не получала данных, так все намного логичней. Благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

Вы перемудрили, шеф.

```
<?php
$cx1 = -1.2; 
$cx2 = 0; 
$delta = 0.5;

function f_compare($x1, $x2, $type) {
    //global $x1, $x2;
    print '<br>f_compare<br>';
    print_r ($x1);
    print_r ($x2);
    return true;
}

//Исследующий поиск
function cycle($cx1, $cx2, $delta, $type) {
    global $cx1, $cx2, $delta; $x = array(); $x2 = array();
    if ($type==1) {$x[0]=$cx1; $x2[0]=$cx2;}
    print '<br>cycle<br>';
    print_r ($x);
    print_r ($x2);
    echo f_compare($x,$x2,$type);
}
cycle($cx1, $cx2, $delta, 1);
```